# php socket data streaming server (mp3)

Tags: php, sockets, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I'm trying make a php server for voice chat using socket. i can send to client a plain data such as html etc.. but i want to send voice data and i'm firstly testing it with a mp3 file. my server code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    set_time_limit(0);

    define('IP', '192.168.56.1');
    define('PORT', '5000');
    define('MAX_CLIENT', 10);

    require_once 'lib/socket.php';

    $socket = new socket();
    $socket->run();
    while (TRUE){
        $socket->accept_multi_client();
        $socket->speak();
    }

?>
```

and my server class :

```
<?php

class socket {

    public static $address = IP;
    public static $port = PORT;
    public static $max_clients = MAX_CLIENT;
    public static $client_socks;
    public static $sock;
    public static $read;

    function run() {
        if (!(socket::$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }

        echo "Socket created \n";

        // Bind the source address
        if (!socket_bind(socket::$sock, socket::$address, socket::$port)) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }

        echo "Socket bind OK \n";

        if (!socket_listen(socket::$sock, socket::$max_clients)) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }

        echo "Socket listen OK \n";

        echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

        //array of client sockets
        socket::$client_socks = array();
    }

    function accept_multi_client() {
        //prepare array of readable client sockets
        socket::$read = array();

        //first socket is the master socket
        socket::$read[0] = socket::$sock;

        //now add the existing client sockets
        for ($i = 0; $i < socket::$max_clients; $i++) {
            if (socket::$client_socks[$i] != null) {
                socket::$read[$i + 1] = socket::$client_socks[$i];
            }
        }

        //now call select - blocking call
        if (socket_select(socket::$read, $write, $except, null) === false) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            print("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }

        //if ready contains the master socket, then a new connection has come in
        if (in_array(socket::$sock, socket::$read)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < socket::$max_clients; $i++) {
                if (socket::$client_socks[$i] == null) {
                    socket::$client_socks[$i] = socket_accept(socket::$sock);

                    //display information about the client who is connected
                    if (socket_getpeername(socket::$client_socks[$i], socket::$address, socket::$port)) {
                        echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
                    }

                    //Send Welcome message to client
                    /*$message = "\n";
                    //$message .= "Enter a message and press enter, and i shall reply back \n";
                    socket_write(socket::$client_socks[$i], $message);*/
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function speak() {

        for ($i = 0; $i < socket::$max_clients; $i++) {
            if (in_array(socket::$client_socks[$i], socket::$read)) {

                $input = socket_read(socket::$client_socks[$i], 1024);
                echo $input;
             /*   if ($input == null) {
                    //zero length string meaning disconnected, remove and close the socket
                    unset(socket::$client_socks[$i]);
                    socket_close(socket::$client_socks[$i]);
                }
*/
                $output = $this->do_anything($input, $i);
               // echo $output;
                //send response to client
                socket_write(socket::$client_socks[$i], $output);
                socket_close(socket::$client_socks[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function do_anything($input, $i) {

        $filename = 'ee.mp3';
        ob_start();
        //ob_end_clean();
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                print('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'."\n");
                print('Content-Type: audio/mpeg'." ");
                print('Content-Disposition: filename="test.mp3"'."\n");
                print('Content-length: ' . 1129297 ."\n");
                /*print('Cache-Control: no-cache'." ");
                print("Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked"." ");*/



                $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
                $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

            } else {
                print("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            }

            $out = ob_get_contents();

        //ob_end_clean();

        return $out.$contents;
    }

}
?>
```

i can get mp3 file with wget and play with mplayer. but i want play this with a html5 player online.

this is not working with my server:

```
<audio controls>

  <source src="http://192.168.56.1:5000/" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

Comment: that's a nice hack! +1 have you investigated the network traffic? Especially headers? Are you sure you are using the right audio encoding? Do you have a working example? (you could compare the non working file and traffic to that)

Comment: no i have no any working example like this and i have no idea about audio encoding. i just reading mp3 file with php and sending to client. if i download content with wget or my web browser, the file that downloaded is working with a music player

Comment: you could use VLC for example to stream the file and see if it works. (Likely if the file is valid) Then compare to your solution using wirehshark or whatever

Comment: i have tried with mplayer: with mplayer http://192.168.56.1:5000 command. and:Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: 192.168.56.1
Connecting to server 192.168.56.1[192.168.56.1]: 5000...

http_read_response read 0 (i.e. EOF).
No stream found to handle url http://192.168.56.1:5000

Comment: and vlc:Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL '192.168.56.1:5000'. Check the log for details.

Comment: my headers is wrong? or socket type?

Comment: can you share the mp3? would like to test at home.. You could upload the file to rapid share and share the link. (would really like to help!!)

Comment: http://speedy.sh/x8d8F/ee.mp3

Comment: Cool! :) Give me a couple of minutes to test....

Comment: I run `ffmpeg -i ee.mp3` and got: *Header missing*, *Could not find codec parameters (Audio: mp3, 0 channels, s16)*. It's a problem with the mp3. Also I where not able to play it with vlc, mplayer, ...

Comment: ok, i will test with another mp3 file

Comment: its not working with another mp3 file. i tested this mp3 with vlc http://users.skynet.be/fa046054/home/P22/track06.mp3 and working. but if i use my server it is not working.

Comment: One problem I've found with your code: Look at socket::speak().. Uncomment the ob_get_clean() at end.. (but this just a minor problem) .. still investigating

Comment: me too, still working on this, thanks

Comment: I can even get `http://127.0.0.1/stream/test.mp3` in chrome to work. (Note its without html, and php. just the mp3)

Comment: thanks but i want to this for make a voice chat server. it's only first step (mp3). i'm trying to learn.

Comment: Post a packet capture so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I think your problem is here: "I'm trying make a php server for voice chat using socket."